# operator norm bound for sub-block matrix based on bound for whole block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Consider the block matrix
$$
X = \begin{bmatrix}
A &B \\ B^T &C
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $A,B,C$ are all matrices of dimension $n\times n$.

I am interested in finding an upper bound for the operator norm of the $B$ sub-block, i.e. I want to find $\phi$ such that
$$
\|B\|_{\text{op}} \le \phi.
$$
What I have been able to show however is only a bound on the operator norm of $X$, i.e. I have
$$
\|X\|_{\text{op}} \le \gamma.
$$
I am wondering if there is a way to find $\phi$ based on $\gamma$?

An attempt:

it holds for any $y \in \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ that we can partition into two $n$-dimensional pieces $y=[y_1^T, y_2^T]^T$ that

\begin{align*}
\|X\|^2_{\text{op}} 
&\ge \frac{\|X y\|^2_2}{\|y\|^2_2}.
\end{align*}
In particular if we take $y_1 = 0$, then
\begin{align*}
\|X\|^2_{\text{op}} 
&\ge \frac{\left \| \begin{bmatrix} By_2 \\ Cy_2\end{bmatrix}\right \|^2_2}{\|y_2\|^2_2}\\
&= \frac{\|By_2\|^2_2 + \|Cy_2\|^2_2}{\|y_2\|^2_2}\\
&\ge \frac{\|By_2\|^2_2}{\|y_2\|^2_2}.
\end{align*}
Since this holds for any $y_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we can take a sup over $y_2$, so that
$$
\|X\|_{\text{op}}  \ge \sup_{y \in \mathbb{R}^n}\frac{\|By\|_2}{\|y\|_2} = \|B\|_{\text{op}}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You take $\phi=\gamma$, because
$$
\|B\|=\|E_{11}X E_{21}\|\leq \|E_{11}\|\,\|X\|\,\|E_{21}\|=\|X \|.
$$

Comment: ah, that is much nicer than my attempt - thank you